# How to create the plugin for customer registration for create post get the inserted last id in magento2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3

How to create the plugin for customer registration for create post get the inserted last id in magento2.

I tried with an example but it is working.

can you please help me?

di.xml

```
<type name="Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\CreatePost">
    <plugin name="createpost"
            type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Customer\CreatePost"/>
</type>
```

controller/action/createpost

```
public function aroundExecute(
    \Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\CreatePost $subject,
    \Closure $proceed
)
{
    // i need the last inserted id 
}
```

Comment: do you mean you want to customer Primary Id which generated for them?

Comment: yes i need primaryid  created

Comment: If answer help you, upvote and accepted as solutions. so it will help other in community.

Answer (score 1):

> **Try Below Code**

**app/code/VendoerName/ModuleName/etc/frontend**

**di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\CreatePost">
        <plugin name="after_create_account_get_id" type="VendoerName\ModuleName\Plugin\CreatePostPlugin" sortOrder="1" />
    </type>
</config>
```

**app/code/VendoerName/ModuleName/Plugin**

**CreatePostPlugin.php**

```
<?php

namespace VendoerName\ModuleName\Plugin;

class CreatePostPlugin
{
    protected $_customerSession;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
    ) {
        $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
    }

    public function afterExecute(
        \Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\CreatePost $subject,
        $result
    ) {
        echo $this->_customerSession->getCustomer()->getId();
        exit();
        return $result;
    }
}
```

***Note: Your last customer id is your current customer ID. Because in last you have created this customer.***

Answer (score 0):

In your plugin need to try this code.

> $customer = $this->accountManagement
> ->createAccount($customer, $password, $redirectUrl);

After above line try this one.

> $customerId = $customer->getId();